# Mirroring letters using ABCPdf

Tags: c#, abcpdf

I am trying to invert a text so that the mirrored text is saved in the PDF, however, I was not successful, I tried in many ways and what made the most sense was to rotate 360º and invert, but the text has not changed ... I also tried to rotate 180º and it didn't work, I need this mirroring because when printing the printer inverts all content, so I already have to send it inverted so that it can be printed legibly. I'm using ABCPDF's XTranform

```
theDoc.Transform.Rotate(360, theDoc.Rect.Left, (theDoc.Rect.Bottom + theDoc.Rect.Width));
theDoc.Transform.Invert();
string textoPdf = "INSERT THE TEXT");
theDoc.FontSize = 8;
theDoc.AddText(textoPdf);
```

Example final result -> ʇxǝʇ ǝɥʇ ʇɹǝsuᴉ

Comment: I see you have already found a solution...but 360 would rotate back to the original starting position!

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, I was trying every possible way, and the code you put in was one last try before asking.

Comment: For your later reference: `Transform.Invert()` is for generating a transform that does the opposite of the existing transform: e.g., a transform that magnifies 200% and rotates 90 degrees, is inverted by a transform that rotates -90 degrees and magnifies by 50%.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
theDoc.Transform.Magnify(-1, 1, theDoc.Rect.Left, (theDoc.Rect.Bottom + theDoc.Rect.Width));
theDoc.Transform.Invert();
string textoPdf = "INSERT THE TEXT");
theDoc.FontSize = 8;
theDoc.AddText(textoPdf);
```